# How to configure Dev, stage and production Env in Cloudfoundry?

Tags: cloud-foundry

Recently I moved my Spring MVC application from local server to CloudFoundry environment.

In my application I have an environment variable I set at server startup. i.e.

```
PROJ_ENV=-Dcom.abc.app.env=local
```

which is used spring config: `<util:properties id="appProps" location="classpath:${com.abc.app.env}.application.properties" />` and the same is available in DEV, Stage and Production Servers and having respective `application.properties` file which contains environment specific values.

How I can maintain same setup in CloudFoundry? Is there any way to define environment/system variables?

Answer (score 1):

You can set ENV variables with the `vmc` command line tool using `vmc set-env appname varname value`.

Have a look at `vmc help --all` for more info. Also, be aware that env variables names with dots in them are sometimes problematic, this is why Spring sometimes uses capital with underscores as alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update, **vmc** has been deprecated since **Cloud foundry v2**. instead of VMC now its recommended to use

```
cf --help
```

Here is a detail link from vmc source..