# Is there different environment (Dev, Stage, Production) mode in Cloudfoundry?

Tags: cloud-foundry

Is there different environment (Dev, Stage, Production) mode in Cloudfoundry?
Recently I move my Spring MVC application from local setup to CloudFoundry setup thr STS CloudFoundry plugin(just one click to public, awesome feature).

Is there any environment mode i.e. Dev, Stage mode so that I will deploy my application in Dev and Stage env? So tester will do there job and developer will develop new functionality.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure Dev, stage and production Env in Cloudfoundry?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129807/how-to-configure-dev-stage-and-production-env-in-cloudfoundry)

Answer (score 1):

There is no strong concept of an "environment" in Cloud Foundry, but there will be a notion of *space* in the upcoming version that may be used for that very purpose (and other things). You can read more about it here : http://blog.cloudfoundry.org/2012/06/20/heads-up-on-some-new-cloud-controller-features/

For the time being, you can deploy your app multiple times giving it different names (and hence URLs) in the scope of your Cloud Foundry account, OR you can use different accounts if you want to restrict who can do what

Comment: N.B. the default spaces are "development, "staging" and "production" so maybe that's what you needed anyway.